# convert itm.txt data into json format

Tags: http, rust, embedded-linux, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I am working in embedded development. I have successfully got the data from sensors in the itm.txt file. I am reading the sensors data from the itm.txt file and want to post that data in JSON format. However, itm.txt contains non-printable characters:

[image: itm.txt]

When I am reading this file in JSON format I am getting result like this:

[image: JSON format of itm.txt content]

This is my post code:

```
pub async fn post(url: &str) -> Result<(reqwest::Response),Error>{
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
  let content = get_data();
    map.insert("Magnetometer", content);
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let response = client.post(url)
        .json(&map)
        .send().await?;

    Ok(response)
}
```

This is the code to get the file content:

```
pub fn get_data() ->String {

        let mut file = File::open("/tmp/itm.txt")
            .expect("No file found at this location");
        let mut  file_content = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut file_content);
        println!("{}",file_content);
    file_content

}
```

I want this data in JSON format. How can I do that? How can I remove the non-printable characters?

Comment: So you want to remove the non-ascii characters? Or do something else with them?

Comment: @PeterHall  yes i want to remove them from the valuable data

Comment: I want data to be like this:Magnetometer-Direction 
x = 289 y = 116 z = -346
Magnetometer-Direction

Comment: `let file_content: String = file.bytes().filter(u8::is_ascii).collect();` ?

Comment: Actually not _quite_ that because the iterator returned by `bytes()` has a `Result<u8>` as its item, so you will need to make a small change.

Comment: The first question I'd try to answer is why these characters are there. This seems rather odd, so I'd try to address the root cause first, before resorting to some hack to filter them out.

Comment: If these are in any way "correct" they are ascii header and text delimiters, but they do seem a bit random.

Comment: @PeterHall, not fully random, look at "Magnetometer-Direction" and how they placed in between numbers. I think it may be some Unicode modifiers (French language? No, but interesting idea :-). I would like to as the same as Sven asked.

Comment: @SvenMarnach root cause  -- **The ITM protocol works with frames. Each frame has a header and a variable length payload. OpenOCD will receive these frames and write them directly to a file without parsing them. So, if the microntroller sends the string "Hello, world!" using the iprintln macro, OpenOCD's output file won't exactly contain that string.
To retrieve the original string, OpenOCD's output file will have to be parsed. We'll use the itmdump program to perform the parsing as new data arrives.** [here](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/06-hello-world/index.html).

Comment: @PeterHall Can we parse this